# Using the partition theorem in probability questions

Tags: probability

So there is one box and it contains 1 white ball and 1 red ball. When a ball is drawn, it is replaced and another ball of that colour is added to the box.

$A_i$ : the event that the ball is red on round $i$

So for example, $P(A_1)$ is $\frac 12$ and $P(A_2|A_1)=\frac 23$ since another red ball was added after getting a red ball on round one.

I must use the multiplication lemma to finnd the probability that the first ball chosen is white, the second ball is red and the third is white. Then I must find the probability that exactly one of the first three balls chosen is red.

The way in which I have calculated the first part is:

$P(A^{c}_1 ∩ A_2 ∩ A^{c}_3) = P(A^{c}_1)P(A_2|A^{c}_1)P(A^{c}_3|A^{c}_1∩A_2)$

which equals: $\frac 12 * \frac 13 * \frac 12 = \frac {1}{12}$

Now is the correct? I don't think I've used the multiplication lemma correctly in this question as I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find out the Probability $P(W_1,R_2,W_3)=P(W_1)P(R_2|W_1)P(W_3|R_2,W_1)$ which is not the same as exactly obtaining just one Red ball in 3 turns because the red ball can come up at either one of the 3 chances and all 3 have different probabilities due to the twisted set-up of the experiment that you add a ball of the same colour that you draw from the box every time you replace it (the subscripts denote the turn and the letters indicate the result of that particular turn). 
Multiplication rule is also known as the "Chain Rule": If A, B, C are 3 events then $P(A,B,C)=P(A)P(B|A)P(C|A,B)$ which is equal to $P(A)P(B)P(C)$ if the events are independent.

Comment: The question strictly asks: "find the probability that the first ball chosen is white, the second ball is red and the third is white" which is a strict order of W, R, W.

Comment: And that's what I've explained above I believe.

Comment: Sorry misread it. My notation may be incorrect in terms of the use of the intersections, but the calculation of: $\frac 12 * \frac 13 * \frac 12 = \frac {1}{12}$ would be correct then?>

Comment: Actually no, I've stated in my notation that round 1 should not be red, round 2 should be red and round 3 should not be red.

Comment: Your notation is correct and so is your answer but I've explained more because your statement "Then I must find the probability that exactly one of the first three balls chosen is red" is not the way to think about this question.

Comment: Haha sorry I literally just realised that! Would I have to manually work this out then?

Comment: Try working out that statement assuming that the red ball comes up at positions 1 or 2 or 3 and you'll realize that they are different. But you've already arrived at the answer for your question yourself which is indeed $\frac{1}{12}$. Chain rule is one of the most important things in Probability.

Comment: Oh well I just tried and it seems like the probabilities are the same. Even then as an initial thought "exactly one of the first 3 balls is red" is something that shouldn't be assumed is the point that I'm trying to make. If you made that assumption then you'll end up adding 3 probabilities instead of just 1.

Comment: Yeah that's the thing I am confused about... each different way (three ways) comes out with 1/12. Do I multiply that by 3 for the three different ways that red can be in the first three rounds?

Comment: In this case you can but it's good to compute the 3 probabilities separately as a sanity check since it doesn't look very intuitive that the probability will be the same wherever red wants to turn up i.e. at slots 1 or 2 or 3. $P(R_1,W_2,W_3)=P(W_1,R_2,W_3)=P(W_1,W_2,R_3)=\frac{1}{12}$

Comment: Yes I understand. So the probability exactly one of the first three balls is red is $\frac 14$ or $\frac {1}{12}$? - I'm not sure whether you add the probabilities together or not since it is three separate cases.

Comment: You need to add the probabilities. $P(\text{1 ball is red}) = P(R_1,W_2,W_3 \cup W_1,R_2,W_3 \cup W_1,W_2,R_3)$ . The 3 events are disjoint and hence their probabilities add up.